# mysql.service location on Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I need to edit the `mysql.service` file to make MySQL automatically restart when it crashes.  I'm working with a pretty much stock Ubuntu 18.04 server install and followed these instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04 for a pretty much stock MySQL install.

My concern is I'm not sure where to edit `mysql.service`. If I do this:

```
sudo updatedb
locate mysql.service
```

I get this:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/mysql.service
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/mysql.service
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/mysql.service
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/mysql.service
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/name=systemd/system.slice/mysql.service
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/mysql.service
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/mysql.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service
```

This is strange because I'm used to systemd `.service` files being located in `/etc/systemd/system`.  Since the path is similar, I would be inclined to suppose that `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` is probably the file I should edit.  However if anybody could provide some additional information on the following that would be great:

1. Is `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` the file I should be editing?
2. Why are there so many `mysql.service` files?  This seems to cause confusion.
3. What is `multi-user.target.wants` ?  Should I change the `mysql.service` file in there also?
4. Some simple googling reveals that `lxcfs` is short for Linux Containers, should I change any of the `mysql.service` files in there ?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share links OR here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3  for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis when done editing OS and running at least 7 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files in */lib/systemd/system* should not be edited by the admin directly and should be left as they are. Those files belong to an installed package and updates and/or changes could break things.

---

To modify existing `systemd` files and configuration like the `.service` files, `systemd` provides the */etc/systemd/system* path, which overrides files and settings found in */lib/systemd/system*.
So, if you e.g. have two `.service` files as follows,

```
/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
```

the one located at */etc/systemd/system/mysql.service* will be used when entering commands like `systemctl [start|stop|enable|disable] mysql.service`.

---

Additionally, `systemd` provides *drop-in ".d" directories* which allows to just change or add a single option of the `.service` file in */lib/systemd/system*. You can use `systemctl edit mysql.service` to create such a drop-in *.d* directory.
All you need to enter then is the section (e.g. `[Service]`, `[Unit]`, ... ) and the option you want to change.
Since you want to change the restart behaviour, do a `systemctl edit mysql.service` and enter the lines as follows.

```
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
```

This will create a folder

```
/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
```

and the override file

```
/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf
```

which contains the lines you entered earlier. You can also manually create the files and folders.

I would prefer this method over copying the whole `.service` file, as the package updates bring changes, you only have to take care of the single changes you have altered.

---

In any case, when working with `systemd` and doing changes to configuration files, one has to enter

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

to activate the changes.

---

Do not change anything else like `lxcfs` related things. The `multi-user.target.wants` is just an organizational method of `systemd` to group services together that shall be started for the `multi-user` target. Targets in `systemd` replaces the old `init 0 1 2 3 4 5 6` method.
Some of the double `mysql.service` files, will be symbolic links that point to your actual `.service` file.

---

Please also see the manpages as follows.

```
man systemctl
man systemd.unit
man systemd.service
man systemd.target
```